# Bootstrap 3 - how to have container full-width on one side only

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make it so the text on the left stays in the position it is in but the red block becomes full-width on the right side.

[image]

This is the code below which is using Bootstrap 3.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-3 -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row row-split">
      <div class="col-sm-7">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h2 class="hero__title primary-font dullblue">Some really cool text.</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="hero__paragraph secondary-font">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <button class="hero__button secondary-font">Shop Now</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5 hero__background">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the left white block with text to take up half and the red to take up half on the right?

Comment: @dmikester1 Yes, but I want to to keep the container on the left (so the text is still padded, but the red to take the full width (with no padding).

Comment: First create your two containers, left and right.  `<div class='row'><div class='col-6'>text here</div><div class='col-6 red-back'></div>`.  Then you can add an additional div inside the first column to hold the text and style that however you want it.

Comment: Also, why are you using Bootstrap 3?  That is very outdated, we are on 5 now.

Comment: @dmikester1 there plenty reasons to do it. Espacially if you have a larger website or Twitter blog you have so much content that it is often harder to convert the entire content to a newer framework. It's far easier and faster to maintain the old framework when doing minor design changes.

Comment: @ChristopherPantelli Is this what you are looking for?  Click on "Open Sandbox" to view the code.  https://h61tu.csb.app/